# Do Like buttons work with test users?

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-like

(This is perhaps a simplified version of a previous, unresolved post: [How do I get my OpenGraph objects to be "liked" properly?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11438137/how-do-i-get-my-opengraph-objects-to-be-liked-properly)), but, anyway:

- I set up a page on my site with OG metatags to identity the page as type video.movie.  The page lints properly.
- A TEST USER clicks on the like button.
- The button behaves properly: it dims, shows "like" with a checkbox, and increments the like counter (in this case from 0 to 1).
- The user's FB profile page shows a "Joe likes this link" entry.

But:

- None of the user's friends get an entry for this like in their feeds.
- If I refresh the page containing the like button, the button goes back to its original state: "like" with a small Facebook logo, and with a like count of 0.
- Running https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://the-page" returns zero for everything.
- Running the page through the linter shows no likes in the Graph API representation (during any of these steps).

So this is definitely not working the way it seems like it should.  Any advice?  Is any of this due to my doing this with test users?  Is there any reason that test users' likes should not persist across time?  Or, will all this magically start to work when the site goes live with real people?

Comment: The only time I've seen this happen is when the Like button is pointing to a page whose OG meta data is invalid in some way. Have you ran your page through the [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if there's any errors preventing the Like going through?

P.s. test users can certainly Like things, yes. I have been testing this with my project and when it works, it works like you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks, but, no, the page lints properly.  Meanwhile, I did the obvious test of Liking the page from a "real" FB account: The Like counter was properly incremented and, so far, has survived a page refresh.  The Like also shows up in the results of the FBML query.  I've got no explanation for this, but it's at least encouraging...